# Azure API does not have authorization

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to read `databases/syncGroups` from api.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;

var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

azure = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

azure.SqlServers.SyncGroups.GetBySqlServer(resourceGroupName, serverName, databaseName, syncGroupName);
```

The authentication seems to be working, but when I call `SyncGroups.GetBySqlServer` I get

```
The client '***' with object id '***' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/syncGroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/***/databases/***/syncGroups/MyGroup' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

In the message, the clientId and the objectId it's been given the same ID, also, the clientId it's not the one I'm passing. So I don't know if it's normal or it's also something that I'm doing wrong.

I tried to add the `databases/syncGroups/read` to my `subscriptions/***` roles. But it still getting the same error.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong keys.

Here's what I did

1. Install azure-cli

```
brew update && brew install azure-cli
```

2. Create a Service Principal

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name MyApplicatinName
```

```
Changing "MyApplicatinName" to a valid URI of "http://MyApplicatinName", which is the required format used for service principal names
Creating a role assignment under the scope of "/subscriptions/***"
{
  "appId": "***",
  "displayName": "MyApplicatinName",
  "name": "http://MyApplicatinName",
  "password": "***",
  "tenant": "***"
}
```

3. Use the right credentials

```
clientId = appId

clientSecret = password

var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var auth = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials);

azure = auth.WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

That's it!

[reference](https://medium.com/@mauridb/calling-azure-rest-api-via-curl-eb10a06127)